# How can I help port Google Chrome to Linux?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, porting

I really enjoy Chrome, and the sheer exercise of helping a port would boost my knowledge-base.

Where do I start?

What are the fundamental similarities and differences between the code which will operated under Windows and Linux?

What skills and software do I need?

---

#### Note:

The official website is Visual Studio oriented!
Netbeans or Eclipse are my only options.
I will not pay Microsoft to help an Open Source project.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

EDIT: (2/6/10)

A Beta version of Chrome has been released for Linux. Although it is labeled beta, it works great on my Ubuntu box. You can download it from Google:

http://www.google.com/chrome?platform=linux

EDIT: (5/31/09)

Since I answered this question, there have been more new developments in Chrome (actually "Chromium") for Linux: An alpha build has been released. This means it's not fully functional.

If you use Ubuntu, you're in luck: add the following lines to your /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/chromium-daily/ppa/ubuntu jaunty main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/chromium-daily/ppa/ubuntu jaunty main
```

Then, at the command line:

```
aptitude update
aptitude install chromium-browser
```

Don't forget to s/jaunty/yourUbuntuVersion/ if necessary. Also, you can s/aptitude/apt-get/, if you insist.

And.... **Yes**, it works. I'm typing this in my freshly installed Chromium browser right now!

The build is hosted by launchpad, and gave me some security warnings upon install, which I promptly ignored. Here's the website: https://launchpad.net/~chromium-daily/+archive/ppa

***The original answer:***

[Linux Build Instructions](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxBuildInstructions)

Answer (score 5):

Read this article on Chrome and Open Source on Linux:

http://arstechnica.com/journals/linux.ars/2008/09/02/google-unveils-chrome-source-code-and-linux-port

The Google V8 JavaScript Engine is also open source and available here if you want to contribute;

http://code.google.com/p/v8/

If you want to contribute on Chronium, here are the instructions:

http://dev.chromium.org/developers/contributing-code

> [Chromium](http://dev.chromium.org/Home) is an open-source browser
>   project that aims to build a safer,
>   faster, and more stable way for all
>   Internet users to experience the web.
>   This site contains design documents,
>   architecture overviews, testing
>   information, and more to help you
>   learn to build and work with the
>   Chromium source code.

Here is how you can get started:

http://dev.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/getting-started

---

EDIT: Two more questions was added to the original question.

Building on Linux requires the following software:

- Subversion >= 1.4
- pkg-config >= 0.20
- Python >= 2.4
- Perl >= 5.x
- gcc/g++ >= 4.2
- bison >= 2.3
- flex >= 2.5.34
- gperf >= 3.0.3
- libnss3-dev >= 3.12

On Ubuntu 8.04, you can fetch all of the above as follows:

```
$ sudo apt-get install subversion pkg-config python perl g++ bison flex gperf libnss3-dev
```

> **Note**: There is no working
>   Chromium-based browser on Linux.
>   Although many Chromium submodules
>   build under Linux and a few unit tests
>   pass, all that runs is a command-line
>   "all tests pass" executable.